# How to upload image file into the SharePoint 2010 picture library using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-online

I need to upload image file to SharePoint 2010 picture library using javascript.

The requirement is:

1. We have File Upload control
2. Ee have to upload image file from that file upload control

My code is attached below, but does not work.

If anybody has a better solution that would be nice.

```
<script>

function updateListItem() 
{
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem.set_item('Title', My Image);
oListItem.update();
clientContext.load(oListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onQuerySucceeded() 
{

alert('Item updated!');

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
{

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

} 

</script>

<input id="FileUpload" type="File" /><br />
<br />
<input onclick="updateListItem()" id="UploadImage" type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Uploading files in general is not easy in JavaScript as far as I know.

You could use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) with a [polyfill, Jahdrien/FileReader](https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader).

Or you could attach an ajax uploader such as [valums/ajax-upload](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) to the existing picture gallery upload form (`/_layouts/Upload.aspx?IsDlg=1&List=<your list guid>`).

Comment: I am able to add an item to the custom list but not able to upload a file into it.I have written following code for reading a file in java script but got "Undefined object" exception for 'File' -- 
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');
var fStream = File.OpenRead(uploadimagepath);
var newPic = oList.RootFolder.Files.Add(phototitle, fStream);

Comment: You get that because you don't have the native function [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/File) on window (global object), you can see which browsers support this on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). This is why I mentioned polyfills.

Comment: I can not use build in API...

Comment: If you have any other approach using java script then it might be helpful.